# expiry date patent EP 0999335 for Europe - Holland?

Tags: date, expiry

In reference to the patent: [EP0999335A1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0999335A1)

Answer (score 0):

You link to an application. The issued patent associated with that application is [EP0999355B1](https://www.google.com/patents/EP0999335B1). This patent should expire 20 years from the priority date of Nov 6, 1998. Thus I believe the patent will expire on Nov 6, 2018. According to [Espacenet](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/inpadoc?CC=EP&NR=0999335B1&KC=B1&FT=D&ND=&date=20011010&DB=&locale=), the designated countries are: DE ES FR GB IT NL.

Comment: There is also a further step of whether the European patent was validated in Netherlands at all.

Comment: @Maca I saw NL listed in Espacenet.

Comment: @Maca I added the designated countries and a link. Please feel free to edit if I misinterpreted Espacenet.

Answer (score 0):

The patent was filed on 04.11.2019 and will expire 20 years after (06.11.2018 is priority date).
The patent was validated in Netherlands and anual fees have been up to now been paid on time.
Note that the patent application was granted as EP0999355B1, but was amended by limitation procedure on 2011. You now should refer to the claims of [EP0999355B3](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/originalDocument?FT=D&date=20110831&DB=&locale=en_EP&CC=EP&NR=0999335B3&KC=B3&ND=1).